# Another... Query fail: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here as a poster so please excuse me becoming familiar with protocol and use of the site. I am not a software engineer but have written quite a bit over the years.

I am having an issue with a "Query fail: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" and have spent an awful lot of time trying to find the error of my ways. I believe I have done all that I have seen suggested with regards to mysqli_next_result and mysqli_free_result

In php I make a couple of queries and the second one fails with this. If I run the first query twice it is fine. Both queries are calling a stored procedure in mysql via a library function in php. I call item_category followed by item_list. In other places I call item_category twice and it works fine.

phplib excert:

```
    function item_category($category = 0){
        mysqli_multi_query(DBi:: $gissit_dbh, "CALL SP_Item_category" ."(". $category .")") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error(DBi::$gissit_dbh));
        $result = mysqli_store_result(DBi:: $gissit_dbh);
        return $result;
        while($gissit_dbn->more_results()){
            mysqli_next_result($result);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($gissit_dbh);
        }

    //Get all wanted items in this category and its subcategories
    function item_list($category = 0){
        mysqli_multi_query(DBi:: $gissit_dbh, "CALL SP_Item_list" ."(". $category .")") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error(DBi::$gissit_dbh));    
        $result = mysqli_store_result(DBi:: $gissit_dbh);
        return $result;
        while($gissit_dbn->more_results()){
            mysqli_next_result($result);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
```

mysql stored procedures:

item_category:

```
select Id, Name, Parent_Id, Count from Item_Category where Parent_Id = cat_id order by Name
```

item_list:

```
SELECT * FROM `Item_Wanted` WHERE Category_Id IN
    (SELECT Id FROM `Item_Category_Lookup` where Id = int_Parent_Id OR Id_1 = int_Parent_Id OR Id_2 = int_Parent_Id OR Id_3 = int_Parent_Id OR Id_4 = int_Parent_Id)
```

The actual call to the phplib function looks like this:

```
If ($cat < 1){
        $result = item_category($cat);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<div class='col-md-4'><a href= item_wanted.php?cat=" .$row['Id'] .">".$row['Name']." (".$row['Count'].")"."</a></p>"."\r\n </div>";
        }
}

If ($cat > 0){
        $result = item_list($cat);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='col-md-4'><a href= item_wanted.php?cat=" .$row['Id'] .">".$row['Title']."</a></p>"."\r\n </div>";
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I may see some of the issue here now. The functions in phplib are returning before executing the mysqli_next_result and mysqli_free_result. I need to look into changing the way that is coded

Comment: Another update. I moved the code from phplib into the application (where the call was made from). With a couple of little syntax changes I got it to work. I would still rather do this with functions in phplib but cannot see a way to do this